# reference request: Invariant differential operators on the sphere

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, smooth-manifolds, laplacian, differential-operators

Could someone give a reference for the statement:

> "the algebra of $SO(n)$- (or $O(n)$-) invariant operators on the sphere $S^{n−1}$ ($n>2$) is precisely equal to the algebra of polynomials in the Laplace operator"?

Thanks.

Comment: see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138575/invariant-differential-operators-on-real-grassmannians/139068

Comment: Yes, that's the initial reference I linked, but some editor deleted it.